# Shopify CLI 3.x

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to run the local development for my theme in shopify but I'm logged on to a shopify store but when I run "shopify theme dev" I need to log in to my shopify partners account which I don't have since the store is live and running.

All I want is to log in to my store and and work on themes that I have pulled down from github.

[image]

I have tried logout and login and reinstall everything

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a Partner's account? You can do next to nothing without one. If you cannot login to Partners or the store in question, you have to ask the owner of the store to make you a staff member of that store to have any hope of working on it.

Comment: @Philip Are you getting an error like this? ┏━━ Error ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃ You can't use Shopify CLI with development stores if you only have Partner staff member access. If you want to use Shopify CLI to work on a development store, then you should be the store owner or create a staff account on the store.